# Why is neo4j webadmin reporting incorrect node/relationship/property counts?

Tags: neo4j

I created some nodes, relationships and properties in my neo4j server db, and the webadmin Dashboard counters show correct figures. But, after I delete any nodes/relationships, the dashboard still shows the old counts. I deleted all nodes (and consequently relationships) using neoclipse, except the ROOT node (id=0). But still the webadmin shows old counts for nodes/relationships/properties. What's wrong?

NOTE:Also, when I query the DB in the webadmin console, none of the nodes other than the ROOT node is returned (e.g., g.v(1) returns null) which verifies the fact that this node doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting the server. It doesn't update the counts from the deletes until you restart.

*update*
Hmm, right, now I remember about those counts--they're actually NumberOfNodeIdsInUse, so they don't take into account deletes, but rather are the number of ids issued, which doesn't get cleared out unless you configure it to reuse nodeids.

Comment: yes, the overal number of nodes is calculated from number of IDs taken, so even deleted nodes/rels had taken already some IDs. but when you want to see actual progress when creating new nodes, sometimes is good enough to brute-refresh the whole webadmin (ctr+shift+r in ff and chrome)