# Why are there so much nodes, relationships and properties in the dashboard?

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to neo4j. I installed it a few hours ago and started following the tutorial described in the guide. At most, I created 7 or 8 nodes, and one type of relationship (Knows). I've reaopened neo4j and the dashboard tells me that there are 1870 nodes, 1546 properties, and 2326 relationships. When I go to the data browser, i can actually see node 1870. 
This still confuses me, even after having seen this posts: [Neo4j Overview Dashboard returns wrong node/relationship/property counts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012120/neo4j-overview-dashboard-returns-wrong-node-relationship-property-counts) or this other one: [Why is neo4j webadmin reporting incorrect node/relationship/property counts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486534/why-is-neo4j-webadmin-reporting-incorrect-node-relationship-property-counts)

What I i understood from them was that the dasboard doesn't necessarily show the real quantity of nodes, relationships, etc. But then, why can I actually see node 1870? Doesn't this afect whatever graph I'm trying to create? I imagine it does affect it, and that i have to delete the .db dile to start again? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The dashboard should the highest id in use for nodes, rels and props - and not exact counts. Id's are requested in chunks that's why your seeing a difference.

For exact node count do:

```
start n=node(*) return count(n)
```